# A question on thermal stresses

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, stresses

I'm studying strength of materials at undergrad level and was taking a test in the same. One of the questions from the test goes like this

[image]

In my understanding since the coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha$ of *rod* material is greater than the $\alpha$ of *tube* material, the situation would be like this:

[image]

The washer will leave the contact with tube and there would be no stresses in either of the *tube* and *rod* at the end of heating. However, since I ask this question this is clearly not the case as per the test solutions.

I argue that in these kind of problems the *tube* material needs to have a higher $\alpha$ than the *rod* material only then the washer will not lose contact with the tube.

Please guide me.

Comment: It seems like they may be focusing on the radial expansion

Comment: First of all your reasoning seems correct. Two things spring to mind. A) the expansion coefficients got mixed up. B) the gun metal rod and the steel tube are welded together.

Comment: The gun metal does not pass through the washer - at least according to the drawing.

Comment: @SolarMike The diagram is actually not given, this is just what I have inferred from the question. As also pointed out by others on this thread, the question has an ambiguity, it doesn't clarify whether the rod and tube are attached to the washer. Perhaps I should report this question for improvements on the website I found it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is correct, as the problem didn't indicate the washer is rigidly attached to the steel tube.

The remaining possibility is the stress between the washer and the gun metal, if the washer is a metal with a smaller thermal expansion coefficient than the gun metal.

The picture below is a plate with a plug in the middle, when both are the same metal, they expand together as shown; when different metals are put together, stress at the interface could result, if the plug (the gun) expands more than the plate that has a lower thermal expansion coefficient.

[image]

You can find the difference in expansion by comparing the expanded areas of the plug made by steel and made by the gun metal using the equation below:

- **THERMAL EXPANSION IN TWO DIMENSIONS**
  For small temperature changes, the change in area ΔA is given by ΔA = 2αAΔT, where ΔA is the change in area A, ΔT is the change in temperature, and α is the coefficient of linear expansion.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that both end(S) are screwed as per the question's verbatim text. Then there will be stress both in the steel tube and in the rod.

Then we can calculate the thermal expansion of steel $\delta L_{steel}$ for say the steel tube alone. the final thermal expansion $\delta L_{final} \ $will be

$$\delta L_{final}=\delta L_ {steel}*\frac{A_{rod}E_{rod}}{A_{steel}E_{steel}}$$

Comment: What does it mean when the problems says, 'screwed'? I think of it as the gun metal rod goes within the tube and is screwed from both sides i.e. bolted, with the help of washers. Even though I haven't shown both sides bolted, but it doesn't seem to me that it will make any difference.

Comment: @HarshitRajput, screwed at the ends can be read as attached at both ends. But I agree there are alternative understandings of the question.

Comment: Oh. Understood.